# read files from linux usb drive under Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, psutil

I use psutil , but seam the F: drive can be seen ...

```
>>> psutil.disk_partitions()
[sdiskpart(device='C:\\', mountpoint='C:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed'), sdiskpa
drom'), sdiskpart(device='E:\\', mountpoint='E:\\', fstype='', opts='cdrom'), sdiskpa
s='rw,removable'), sdiskpart(device='G:\\', mountpoint='G:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your drive formatted? Windows can only read `ntfs` and `fat` formats. You can check this using the windows **disk management** tool:

From http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disk-management-windows-7.htm:

> ### How To Access Disk Management in Windows 7
>
> Click on the **Start** button and then choose **Control Panel**.
>
> Click on the **System and Security** link.
>
> Note: If you're viewing the Large icons or Small icons view of **Control Panel**, you won't see this link so just click on the **Administrative Tools** icon and skip to Step 4.
>
> In the System and Security window, click on the **Administrative Tools** heading located near the bottom of the window.
>
> In the **Administrative Tools** window, double-click on the **Computer Management** icon.
>
> When **Computer Management** opens, click on **Disk Management** on the left side of the window, located under **Storage**.
>
> After a brief loading period, **Disk Management** should now appear on the right side of the **Computer Management** window.
>
> Note: If you don't see **Disk Management** listed, you may need to click on the **|>** icon to the left of the Storage icon.
>
> You can now partition a hard drive, format a hard drive, change a drive's letter, or do whatever else you need to do in Windows 7's Disk Management tool.

Look for drive F and check the formatting. If it is not `ntfs` or `fat`, you will need to reformat it and copy the data again, or install Ext2Read or another program that can read linux-formatted drives under windows (see: https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows).

Comment: I need a python module to make this .